# Alfresco creation of custom data model programmatically

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created a custom data model in Alfresco share. I want to apply values to that custom data programmatically.

Can any one suggest the proper way to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? You want to create nodes based on your new types and assign values to your properties?

Comment: You really need to give some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom control on FTL file and when you define your form in Alfresco share your set the URL of this control.